# Read JSON file from documents folder iOS with javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, json, directory

In my app I need to read a JSON file stored in Documents folder of my iPhone. I saw that exist a method to bridge javascript and objective C. How I can do that? I understand that i should use this method in objective C `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;`, but what I should write in javascript? I found this: [call objective C method from javascript](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/), but I didn't understand how it works. In my app I've to do this:

1. Reach an offer from a mobile site (I made some little mobile site)
2. I store the mobile site local in the Documents folder of my iPhone
3. I generate a JSON file to keep the name, the path and the expire date for the offer. I stored this JSON in Documents folder of my iPhone
4. My app has an "archive" view controller, in which I load a mobile site in which I will to list all offer stored in the device by reading the JSON created

I made the native app and it works, now I've to implement the method to read the JSON file from Documents folder can anyone help me to do this operation? How I can read the JSON from javascript, parse it and show the result in an html dynamic list?

Thank you

CODE UPDATE: for now I wrote this code:

**Objective C snippet**

```
- (void)parseJson {
    // Carico il documento JSON dalla cartella documents
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
    BOOL fileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (fileExist) {
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dictContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        if (dictContent) {
            NSDictionary *sites = [dictContent objectForKey:@"sites"];
            NSArray *site = [sites objectForKey:@"site"];
            NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray *srcs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (int i = 0; i < [site count]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *dictData = [site objectAtIndex:i];
                [names addObject:[dictData objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [srcs addObject:[dictData objectForKey:@"src"]];
            };
            NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataFromObjC([%@, %@])", names, srcs];
            [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Promo" message:@"Non hai ancora salvato nessuna promozione!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Faccio il parse del documento JSON
    // Passo le informazioni parsate al javascript
}
```

In javascript I made a function named `dataFromObjC(names, srcs)`. Below you will find the html code to see what I made:

**Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>  
        <title>Lista coupon</title>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/memoria.js"          type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dataFromObjC(names, srcs) {
                alert(names);
                alert(srcs);
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #000000;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            li {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
            }
            p {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadJson();">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Di seguito trovi tutte le promozioni salvate</p>
            <div id="list">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will be useful to solve it. I used the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, because I found on here a post to read data from objective C to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As you need to read JSON only, then read it by:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);

NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myJson.json"];
NSData *jsonData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:fullPath];
```

then parse it to nsdictionary:

```
id jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

Updated Again:
If you want to call obj c from javascript, you need to define a specific URL like:

```
http://abc.com/?key=value
```

Then call it from js:

```
function callObjC(){
  location.href='http://abc.com/?key=value';
}
```

Then in shouldStartLoadWithRequest, compare the request's url and the specific URL, it they are the same then do your function.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://abc.com/"]) {
        //comparing urls, if almost the same
        //if you need to pass parameters to Obj C, put them in the URL as my example and explode yourself
        [self anotherMethod];//your method
        return NO;//skip the request, as the link is not valid or we don't want to change the webview
    }

   return YES;
}
```

Your [link provided](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/), it uses a self-defined protocol: js-call rather than http.
It works, but Apple do not recommend it.

Comment: Ok, I know this. But I've to do it in javascript... How I can do that?

Comment: What do you think about this [link](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge)?